# Silverstripe Yml Files Classes

Tags: php, silverstripe

What is the best practice regarding configuration for different Classes in yml config files in Silverstripe?  Specifically is it advisable to access more than one class within a yml file?

Comment: What do you mean with Class declarations? A class is usually not declared in a yml file. Do you mean configurations for different classes?

Comment: configurations for different classes you're correct, I edited my question

Comment: I think this is primarily an opinion-based question. You're free to create as many config files as you like.

Comment: bummzack but do you mean 1 class per config file is the rule?

Comment: No, you can configure as many classes as you want in a single config file. You can read more about the config files here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Entirely up to the developer. My personal opinion would be that having a config per class would be a bit over the top, and become overloaded with many files doing not much, making maintenance a problematic experience.

I think generally a single config file per project (read: module, etc) is quite acceptable. Or, if that's a bit messy and verbose, then a config file per major concern in that project, eg. one for routes, and one for general configuration.

Such as basically the way it is already done with CMS, et al.